# Task created is null in Camunda using singleResult() method

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I was creating a taskService in camunda with the following command, But am getting null task created. Any idea what could be the reason?

```
Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery()
            .processInstanceBusinessKey(businessKey).initializeFormKeys().singleResult()
```

task evaluated to null.

`businessKey` is a valid non-empty string provided.

Answer (score 0):

Either no task instance has been created / is active or the businessKey does not match.
Try less restrictive criteria and see if you get a result, for instance:

```
List<Task> taskList = taskService.createTaskQuery().active().list()
```

Then add the businessKey back and check if it matches. Did you correctly submit the businessKey when starting the instance?

If you only just started the process Instance and have access to the ID then you could also try to use the process instance id as filter criteria:

```
RuntimeService runtimeService = engine.getRuntimeService();
ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("MyProcess");
TaskService taskService = engine.getTaskService();
List<Task> taskList = taskService.createTaskQuery()
        .processInstanceId(processInstance.getId())
        .list();
Task task = taskList.get(0);
```